# Sub-menu for each binding item

Tags: c#, wpf

Following the [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/5149692) from Omer van Kloeten I filled a menu with menu items bound from my observable collection. I got a single menu item for a single collection item. Fine, but I actually want more. I also want to be able to have a menu item with two or three sub items for one collection item. Here is some rough sketch:

```
What I Have         What I Want
+ First Item        + Create First Item
+ Second Item       + Second Item
                      + Delete
                      + Update
```

Here "First Item" has property `Exists = false`, but "Second Item" has it `true`. My current code:

```
public class CollectionItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Exists { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<CollectionItem> items;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        items = new ObservableCollection<CollectionItem>();
        items.Add(new CollectionItem() { Name = "First Item", Exists = false });
        items.Add(new CollectionItem() { Name = "Second Item", Exists = true });
        AllItems.ItemsSource = items;
    }
}

<MenuItem x:Name="AllItems" Header="What I Have">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

How do I mix simple menu items with sub items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I mix simple menu items with sub items?

First, you need to have your data structured appropriately, with collection properties to represent the child, or sub `MenuItem`s. Then, you need to data bind the collection property to the `ItemsSource` property of the parent `MenuItem` using the `MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle`, similar to what you're doing now. You should end up with something like this:

```
public class CollectionItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Exists { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<CollectionItem> CollectionOfSubItems { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
<MenuItem x:Name="AllItems" Header="What I Have">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding CollectionOfSubItems}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a way to have my business model separated from GUI. Is there a way to use `Exists` property?

Comment: Don't get confused here... you have a business model and a UI related model. The UI related model contains all UI related properties required to data bind your `MenuItem`s. The UI related model *may* take some values from the business model, but that doesn't make it a business model. Separate your concerns... we don't save these UI related values - that's just for the UI.

Comment: My app is tiny. Because I would have to make some kind of converters between two models this solution feels like an overkill, and I'm not going to use it, and just do stuff manually. I tested this solution and it does what is written on the box, so if there are no better answers in a week time I'll just accept it.

Comment: How can you have a better answer than the correct answer? Just because you have got confused about which properties go where, that doesn't make this any less correct. All I was saying is that if you need to add UI related properties to help create the UI that you want, that's fine... just don't save those properties. It's not so complicated.

Comment: After adding some helper classes (`CollectionSubItem` of sorts, [RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030)), an interface (that `MainWindow` implements to handle the events, and items use in constructor to create 3 `RelayCommands`) and a `Parent` property to find an item for given sub-item (both can be passed as `CommandParameter`), I finally made it work. Not sure if it's "the best" way, but it works. Thanks.